# Bash files don't run and when running in terminal text editor runs instead (Ubuntu 19)

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, gnome-terminal, sh

I am having a BIG issue with a .sh file. When I try to run it in the terminal, I end up opening a text editor instead (the text editor that runs within the terminal). I tried changing the preferences, to make it ask me every time whether to run it in the terminal or not, I also changed the preferences so that it runs every time, I tried running from the terminal and I tried double clicking it, and all efforts are useless. All are done after giving permission to executable text files to execute. I tried running with bash, running with sh, running with `./filename.sh`, all are in vain...

I checked most of the previous questions asked here and on other websites, and they all didn't help.

I am running it in Ubuntu 19 and I don't know where the issue is, did running sh scripts change in Ubuntu 19?

This is a link to the bash code I am trying to run:
https://github.com/ArduPilot/ardupilot/blob/master/Tools/environment_install/install-prereqs-ubuntu.sh

Comment: Can you [edit] your question and post the content of your script?

Comment: Running scripts haven't changed, i'm on 19.04 and it works the same for me. Can you post the output of `which bash`? That will at least identify if the executable path is the same.

Comment: Pleaae post your `./filename.sh`?? Perhaps your scripts somethink wrong.

Answer (score 1):

To run a script like this it needs to have a shebang in the first line of the file like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
```

And it needs to be made executable with `chmod` in the terminal:

```
chmod u+x ./filename.sh
```